# Largest $f(k)$ such that $E(X) < \frac{E(X^2)^{1/2}}{f(k)}$ when $X > k$

Tags: probability, expected-value, moments

Assume we have a non-negative integer random variable $X$ that only takes values bigger than $k$ (i.e. $P(X \geq k) = 1)$. Denote $p(x) = P(X=x)$. I would like to give an upper-bound on the mean $E(X)$ in terms of $k$ and $E(X^2)^{1/2}$.

**First attempt**: $E(X) = \sum_{x \geq k} p(x)x 
\\ \qquad = \sum_{x \geq k} \sqrt{p(x)} \sqrt{p(x)} x
\\ \qquad \leq \sqrt{\sum_x p(x) \sum_x p(x) x^2} \ (Cauchy-Schwarz)
\\ \qquad \leq E(X^2)^{1/2}$

**Second attempt**: $E(X) = \sum_{x \geq k} \sqrt{p(x)} \sqrt{p(x)} x 
\\ \qquad \leq \sqrt{\sum_{x \geq k} p(x)} \sqrt{\sum_{x \geq k} p(x)x^2} \ (Cauchy-Schwarz)\\ \qquad \leq \sqrt{P(X \geq k)} \sqrt{E(X^2)} 
\\ \qquad \leq \sqrt{E(X)/k} \sqrt{E(X^2)} \ (Markov)
\\ \qquad \leq \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{E(X^2)}}{k}} \sqrt{E(X^2)} \ (Cauchy-Schwarz)
\\ \qquad \leq \frac{E(X^2)^{3/4}}{k^{1/2}}$

**Third attempt**: $E(X) = \sum_{x \geq k} p(x)x 
\\ \qquad \leq \frac{1}{k} \sum_x p(x) x^2 
\\ \qquad \leq \frac{E(X^2)}{k}$

Ideally, I would like to have $E(X^2)^{1/2}$ at nominator but still a dependency on $k$ at denominator. However, I suspect that the best I can prove is $E(X) \leq \frac{E(X^2)^{(1+\eta)/2}}{k^{\eta}}$ for any $0 \leq \eta \leq 1$... Am I true?

Comment: In my opinion, the second attempt is of no use, since it is worse than the first one. After the first attempt you may get something like 
$$E(X)\le k+\sqrt{E(X-k)^2}$$.

Comment: Just to be clear, is $f(k)$ expected to be universal, i.e. independent of $X$?

Comment: It seems that the third attempt is of no use too, because of the trivial inequality $E(X^2)\ge k^2.$ That implies $E(X) \leq \frac{(E(X^2))^{(1+\eta)/2}}{k^{\eta}}$.

Comment: To answer you question, please consider the case $X\equiv k$ a.s.

Comment: Yes $f(k)$ is expected to be universal. But as pointed out by Viktor, we cannot do better: since $k \leq E(X)$ and $E(X)^2 \leq E(X^2)$ we have $k^{\eta} E(X) \leq E(X)^{1+\eta} \leq E(X^2)^{(1+\eta)/2}$ and thus $E(X) \leq \frac{E(X^2)^{(1+\eta)/2}}{k^{\eta}}$, which is tight using $X = k$.

Comment: Another bound, although not quite satisfying the question's requirements: $E(x) \leq k + [E(X-k)^2]^{1/2}$, which is tight for degenerate distributions of the form: $p(x=k+a) = 1$.